# Ignore incorrect compiler waring?

Tags: objective-c, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have a notification and its handler:

```
- (void) addObservers
{
...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleColumnCreated:) name:NNColumnCreated object:nil];
…
}

- (void) handleColumnCreated:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [_formFields makeInfoForColumn:[notification object] FieldInfo:_propertiesViewController.representedObject];
    [self setActiveColumn:[notification object]];
}

- (void) setActiveColumn:(id)theColumn
{
    if (_activeColumn != nil)
    {
        [_activeColumn setBackgroundColor:_oldColumnColor];
    }

    _activeColumn = theColumn;
    _oldColumnColor = [_activeColumn backgroundColor];
    [_activeColumn setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    [_window makeFirstResponder:theColumn];

    [_propertiesViewController setRepresentedColumn:[theColumn info]];
}
```

On the last line of setActiveColumn I'm getting a warning that says the parameter I'm sending to setRepresentedColumn: is of the wrong type. Yet when I trace the line with the debugger, [theColumn info] resolves to the correct type and the line executes correctly.

I could ignore the warning, but I don't think that's a good idea. I haven't been able to figure out why the compiler thinks that `[theColumn info]` yields an object of the wrong type. Help!

Comment: No, no, no. Xcode doesn't do anything. It's the compiler that emits the warnings.

Comment: It's possible to store objects of a different type inside of other object types.  Just because the debugger resolves something correctly, doesn't mean that you didn't do something boneheaded earlier in program execution.

Comment: How is theColumn created, how is the `info` field populated, and how is `setRepresentedColumn:` declared?   The rest is just noise in the context of the question.

Answer (score 3):

The declared type of whatever `info` method you're calling on your `theColumn` parameter doesn't match the declared type of the argument to `setRepresentedColumn:`. You can keep this from causing a warning by casting to the correct type.

e.g., if `setRepresentedColumn:` is declared thusly:

```
- (void)setRepresentedColumn:(MyColumnObject *)column
```

then you can change that last line to:

```
[_propertiesViewController setRepresentedColumn:(MyColumnObject *)[theColumn info]];
```

Note, however, that all you're doing is telling the compiler, "Trust me, I know what type this object is," to make it shut up... you're still prone to runtime errors if `[theColumn info]` ever returns something other than a `MyColumnObject`.